# Currying and compiler design

Tags: currying, compiler-construction

This is a homework question:

> Explain the transformations the type
>   of a routine undergoes in partial
>   parameterization.

So far I understand currying. But I cannot find any resources on how a function like this is implemented by the compiler in memory. Could I be pointed in the right direction, maybe keywords to search for or links to resources or possibly an explanation here of how the compiler generates the type and symbol table among other things thats related to the question.

Thanks.

Comment: In reading your question, I immediately think of the ML language family, which explicitly answers your question in its very notation! It would be well worth your time to play around with OCaml.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currying is the conversion of n argument functions into n unary functions:

Example, if you have a ternary function f :: t1 x t2 x t3 -> t you can represent this function as

```
f1 :: t1 -> (t2 -> (t3 -> t))
```

In other words, f1 is a function which takes an argument of type t1 and returns a function of type f2.

```
f2 :: t2 -> (t3 -> t)
```

f2 is a function which takes an argument of type t2 and returns a function of type f3.

```
f3 :: t3 -> t
```

f3 is a function which takes an argument of type t3 and returns type t.

Example, if f(a,b,c) = a+b*c then:

```
f3(C) == c1+c2*C where c1 and c2 are constant.
f2(B) == f3(C) where c1 is constant and c2 is replaced with B.
f1(A) == f2(B) where c1 is replaced with A.
```

In functional languages, functions are first class citizens so its common to have them as return type.

Comment: Do you have any links to resource describing specific algorithms that can be used to transform the abstract syntax tree representation of a multi-parameter function into a curried functions?

Comment: @Richard Cook, my only source right now is some 15 year old treeware version of "Compiler Design" by Reinhard Wilhelm and Dieter Maurer (with emphasis on front ends for logic/functional and oo languages). If I have time during the holidays I can add some information.

Answer (score 0):

Currying is like fixing a parameter of the function. What you really need to modify is the prototype of the function called.. if you have for example `retn_type function(param1, param2)` and you currying it on first parameter you set it to a fixed value and you obtain a new function `retn_type(param2)` that can be called and passed in a different way from the original one.

Actually you can obtain it in a compiler in many ways or hacks but the core of everything to its simplicity is just to redefine a new version that is linked to first one. So when you call `retn_type(param2)` you execute the same code of first function assuming that parameter1 is specified by curryfication.